# CPU usage according to lxde applet and task manager is different than top

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage, top, lxde

The CPU usage in `top` (`htop`) appears normal but the task manager and lxde CPU applet don't. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

This is Lubuntu 12.04

Is this a bug?

Comment: Next time please check the spelling of tags before creating them. Thank you!